# ModuleNotFoundError in Python3.9

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using python to do some data crunching on a computing node in my University. The computing node has multiple versions of python installed in it. However, every time I run a script using

`$python3 script.py`

by default python3.6 is chosen and I do not understand how to do I make python3.9 as the default version while running any script. Any guidance on this will be appreciated.

Further, I found a workaround on google and tried running my script with the command

`$python3.9 script.py`

This does choose python3.9 as the version to run, however it throws `ModuleNotFoundError` when I try to import any third party library say `pandas`. I have all the needed third party modules installed in the system and they work fine when I run a script with

`$python3 scipt.py`

I have to run the script using python3.9 because one of the modules fails if not run with python3.9. Do you have any suggestions on why none of the third party modules are not available when I switch to python3.9?

Comment: Module installs are per python install/version by default. You'll need to install the modules again for the other python version. I also recommend using a venv to keep your dependencies organized.

Comment: I'm assuming you are under linux. don't change the system python as the system uses it and you can cause instability. the reason you are getting module not found is because you didn't install pandas in your 3.9 enviroment. you can install it with `python3.9 -m pip install pandas` you should familiarize yourself with [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) and use that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a [python virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) it is highly recommended.

minimal example:

> create venv
>
> ```
> python3.9 -m venv path/to/new/vnenv/folder
> ```
>
> activate venv (in linux)
>
> ```
> source path/to/new/vnenv/folder/bin/activate
> ```
>
> activate venv (in windows)
>
> ```
> path/to/new/vnenv/folder/Scripts/activate.bat
> ```
>
> install packages
>
> ```
> pip install pandas
> ```
>
> run script
>
> ```
> python script.py
> ```
>
> deactivate venv
>
> ```
> deactivate
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Each version of Python can only use the modules installed with the corresponding version of pip. You can use `python3.6 -m pip install [module]` to install it for a specific version.

The way of making a given version of Python the default one for a system is specific to every distribution, in Debian for example you would use `update-alternatives --config python` and then select the one you want.

`venv` is also an alternative allowing you to create virtual environments for each project, thus managing your dependencies inside and avoiding having to install dependencies system-wide. Here is the doc : https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/venv.html.